# Sequelize: TypeError: hasOne is not a function

Tags: node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js, associations, model-associations

Hi I am new to Sequelize the hasOne association is not working for me I am trying to make two tables a table of

1. Dealer containing a dealer's name and description
2. DealerProducts containing the Dealers products and prices as well as the table1 as the FKEY (which I want hasOne to make for me the FKEY)

So I'm making 3 files one for each of them and then an index.js file to gather them in and make their relevant association

Here are those files:

dealer-model.js

```
module.exports = (sequelize = require('../db')) => {

  const { DataTypes } = require('sequelize');

  const Dealer = sequelize.define('Dealer', {
    did: {
      type: DataTypes.UUID,
      defaultValue: DataTypes.UUIDV4,
      allowNull: false,
      primaryKey: true
    },
    name: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      allowNull: false,
      unique: true,
      validate: {
        len: [1, 50]
      }
    },
    description: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      allowNull: true,
    },
  }, {
    tableName: 'dealers',
    timestamps: true,
    createdAt: 'created_at',
    updatedAt: 'updated_at',
    // paranoid: true
  })

  return Dealer;
}
```

dealer-products-model.js

```
module.exports = (sequelize = require('../db')) => {
  const { DataTypes } = require('sequelize');

  const DealerProduct = sequelize.define('DealerProduct', {
    dpid: {
      type: DataTypes.UUID,
      defaultValue: DataTypes.UUIDV4,
      allowNull: false,
      primaryKey: true
    },
    product_name: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      allowNull: false,
      unique: true,
      validate: {
        len: [1, 100]
      }
    },
    type: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      allowNull: true,
      validate: {
        len: [1, 100]
      }
    },
    description: {
      type: DataTypes.TEXT,
      allowNull: true
    },
    price: {
      type: DataTypes.DECIMAL(10, 2),
      allowNull: false
    },
    quantity: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
      allowNull: false
    }
  }, {
    tableName: 'dealer_products',
    timestamps: true,
    createdAt: 'created_at',
    updatedAt: 'updated_at',
    // paranoid: true
  })

  return DealerProduct;
}
```

Then the index.js

```
module.exports = async (sequelize = require('../db')) => {
  const { DataTypes } = require('sequelize');
  const User = require('./user-model');
  const Dealer = require('./dealers-model');
  const DealerProduct = require('./dealer-products-model');
  User(sequelize)
  Dealer(sequelize)
  DealerProduct(sequelize)

  DealerProduct.hasOne(Dealer, {
    foreignKey: {
      type: DataTypes.UUID,
      allowNull: false,
      name: "dealers_did"
    }
  });

  Dealer.belongsTo(DealerProduct);

  sequelize.sync({alter: true}); //force: true
}
```

This is making the tables for my postgres but association is not working as I am not making a FKEY column for the DealerProducts

and this is the error I am getting

TypeError: DealerProduct.hasOne is not a function

Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**UPDATE**

My answer was as simple as saving the Dealer and DealerProduct as variables then using the variables as the hasOne example:

````
 const dealer = Dealer(sequelize)
 const dealerProduct = DealerProduct(sequelize)

  dealer.hasOne(dealerProduct, {
    foreignKey: {
      type: DataTypes.UUID,
      allowNull: false,
      name: "dealers_did"
    }
  });

  dealerProduct.belongsTo(dealer);```

So this worked
````